# How to make this preg_replace work with these character replacement?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi,

I am struggling to understand the logic in regular expressions. I have this code:

```
preg_replace("~\b$replace\b~","",$file);
```

Where $replace is a numeric value but it should be encapsulated inside [] to look like this: [33] so I did this:

```
preg_replace("~\b[$replace]\b~","",$file);
```

and this:

```
$replace = "[".$value."]";
preg_replace("~\b[$replace]\b~","",$file);
```

but none will parse. What is the logic behind this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `$file` a pointer or path, or is it the content? I ask because the first example seems to work for me when I use it for the string `[33]`, I get `[]`.

Comment: Its a string that looks like this: [12][33] so it should delete the whole expression [33] including the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets have special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape them to match them literally.

You shouldn't use `\b` around the square brackets. `\b` matches a word boundary, which means a word character next to a non-word character. So unless there's an alphanumeric character before the `[` and after `]`, it won't match.

```
preg_replace("~\[$replace\]", "", $file);
```

And once you've done that, you don't actually need to use `preg_replace()`. This is just a fixed string with no regexp patterns, so just use `str_replace()`

```
str_replace("[$replace]", "", $file);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. I was wasting my time with preg_replace.